# Android Drawable doesn't match_parent to it's layout

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I'm setting a `RelativeLayout`'s background with a `drawable` and here is the [correct result](http://i.imgur.com/JLsvefl.png) when opening the activity first time.

But, when I switch to another activity (with same background), and go back to old activity, background is scaling to it's drawable size [which is wrong](http://i.imgur.com/oWi762i.png).

Or sometimes, it's same in other activity too(with wrong size). Here is the common XML layout I use for layout's root element:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundLayForBg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- custom childs -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can cause to this problem?

Edit: If I set a background color, I'm not getting any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this approach:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!-- set background of activity using ImageView -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

 <!-- custom childs -->

</RelativeLayout>
```